# Internet compressor?

Tags: networking, compression

I have an internet connection which has highest speed = minimum speed. Both are 30mbps. Although stable, it is too slow for downloading any large file or video in a reasonable time. My motherboard and my router are all Gigabit-capable, so the only bottleneck is the ISP limit. Is there a way that compresses my internet connection, like Opera Turbo but for all internet traffic?

Comment: How large is "large"? Are you specifically looking to download high-quality videos (like 4K)?

Comment: Just 1080p is slooooooow.

Comment: Also, Steam is quite unbearable. For example, I need ~8hrs to download r6s, which most of the players I know only needs 1-2, or even less.

Comment: If there was a way to compress it more do you think it wouldn’t be used already while compressing the files in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

There is no such service for general Internet access, because the way it works inherently depended on understanding and transforming the files you download. Opera Turbo worked with HTTP because the proxy understood what HTTP looks like, and the browser was fine with it delivering modified data. (Since it was integrated into the browser, Turbo was in a position to intercept TLS/HTTPS requests – something that a general VPN cannot do.)

Regarding the last point: even though there are VPN protocols which compress IP packets, that's mostly useless because encrypted data just doesn't compress. It really needs to be done at application protocol level.

More than that, different files compress differently. Most online video formats are already compressed such that the only way to squeeze them even more is to reencode them in *lower quality*. That requires quite a bit of computing resources, unless you dial quality down to the point that it somewhat defeats the point of downloading massive high-quality files in the first place. (Just go for regular 1080p if you want it faster.)

Similarly, most game files are already compressed and packed into proprietary formats that the proxy wouldn't understand, while packet-level compression would likely get no more than 1–2% reduction.

So even if such a service existed, it would only exist for the web (HTTP), and I would doubt its usefulness even then.

Comment: As someone who has had an 8 Mbps connection for the last several years, I'd say you just need more patience.

Comment: "patience" when the game is 100GB or more

Comment: 100GB @ 30mbps is going to take many hours. I think patience is going to be your only option here.